# Avoiding missing row after summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I'm using RStudio Version 0.98.1028 on windows. Summarising a multi level data frame, package `dplyr`, using the function sum(), I lost a row, which had `sum = 0`. In other words, if my original data frame was something like

```
group <- as.factor(rep(c('X', 'Y'), each = 1, times = 6))
type <- as.factor(rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 2, times = 3))
day <- as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 4))

df = data.frame(type = type, day = day, value = abs(rnorm(12)))
df = df[day != 1 | type != 'a',]
```

and I summarise it

```
df1 = df %>%
    group_by(day, type) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(value))
```

then I get one missing row, which is the interaction between `day = 1` and `type = a`, which I would like to have (even if it's `0`...)

Thanks in advance!

EB

Comment: Could you give a small reproducible example that represents the problem?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll edit the question

Comment: Thant's exactly the point indeed! The example I provided here is very simplified with respect to what I'm actually handling, but it's quite representative of my problem...

Comment: @Emiliano In the subset dataset,you don't have that combination row of `day=1` and `type=a`

Comment: @Emiliano It seems to me that you wanted all the combinations even after subsetting.  ie. the combinations that were not in the subset dataset should sum to `0`.  If that is the case, I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(expand.grid(type=unique(df$type), day=unique(df$day)), df1) %>%
                            group_by(day, type) %>%
                            summarise(sum=sum(value, na.rm=TRUE))
#  day type       sum
#1   1    a 0.0000000
#2   1    b 0.5132914
#3   2    a 1.2482210
#4   2    b 0.9232343
#5   3    a 2.0381779
#6   3    b 0.7558351
```

where `df1` is

```
 df1 <- df[day != 1 | type != 'a',]
```

Comment: I think that `df[day != 1 | type != 'a',]` is not what the OP thought it was, so perhaps it's better to replace it with code that does the subset on the basis of df's variables.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I will wait for the OP's response as I did commented on the post.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you are suggesting does not work properly and the reason for this is that I actually have a strange database, with many missing interaction between the variable day and another variable. With `df[day != 1 | type != 'a',]` I was only trying to reproduce my case. I re-wrote my script. Many thanks for your help!